# Conditional query across rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery to try and establish instances where distinct sessions have had a number of faults flag in the same session, and return one of the specific faults. Example:

```
session_id  fault
1234        a
1234        b
1234        c
1234        d
5678        a
5678        c
9012        b
4567        a
4567        c
```

In the above table, I would be looking for distinct sessions where faults a,b,c,d have occurred and return only the row with the session_id and fault c (along with other columns in this row) for further analysis. I have tried different WHERE statements but am unsure what session_id should equal.

Ideally this will return one row for each distinct session. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE session_id = ?
AND fault IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
WHERE fault = 'c'
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you find below conditional agregation

```
select session_id from table
where fault IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
group by session_id
having count( distinct fault)=4
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ANY_VALUE(t)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t  
WHERE fault IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
GROUP BY session_id
```

it returns ALL columns in that one selected row

If you need logic of selecting last (let's say sorted by fault) - yo can use below version

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY fault DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t  
WHERE fault IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
GROUP BY session_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want fault "c", then

```
select (array_agg(t order by (fault = 'c') desc limit 1))[ordinal(1)].*
from t
where fault in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
group by session_id
having count(distinct fault) = 4;
```

If faults are not repeated for a session (as in your example data), you can use:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
      where fault in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
     ) t
where cnt = 4 and fault = 'c';
```

If they can be repeated, you can use `count(distinct)` instead:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(distinct fault) over () as cnt
      from t
      where fault in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
     ) t
where cnt = 4 and fault = 'c';
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer with my example but yes the faults can be repeated so your bottom example would work I think. Can I ask what 'over ()' is doing and how this query would differ from using the 'having count( distinct fault)=4' used in another answer?

Comment: @Matt . . . Those are window functions.  The first query returns only one row with a fault of "c" for each session.  The last query returns *all* rows with a fault of "c".

Answer (score 0):

Lots of other good answers, but this can be solved with basic principles: Select rows with fault C, select rows with 4 faults (or whatever criteria you need), then join.

```
with faults_c as ( 
  select * from table where fault = c
),
faults_4 as (
  select session_id from table 
  group by 1 
  having count(distinct fault) = 4
)
select *
from faults_c
inner join faults_4 using(session_id)
```