# SQL query to find all UUIDs with a logical expression of flags set

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, having

I have a SQLite database with ~30 million rows with UUIDs and a flag column (among other columns) and I want to return all UUIDs that satisfy a logical expression of the flags.

```
  UUID | flag | ...
   1   | "a"  |
   1   | "b"  |
   1   | "a"  |
   2   | "b"  |
   2   | "c"  | 
   3   | "a"  |
```

For example I want to return all UUIDs that have flag ("a" AND ("b" or "c")) over all rows. In the above table only UUID=1 satisfies that constraint.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936344/conditional-query-across-rows) is a similar question but it only asks about the case of having all 4 flags set --- there is no disjunction --- so the solutions there don't work here.

edit: @forpas `HAVING SUM` solution is what I was looking for but I ending up solving the problem by creating a user defined aggregate function before I saw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation with the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT UUID
FROM tablename
GROUP BY UUID
HAVING SUM(flag = 'a') > 0
   AND SUM(flag IN ('b', 'c')) > 0;
```

You can add as many conditions as you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=82cd32939f7365da2c9f66724f8d250a).

Answer (score 0):

you  can use `EXISTS` if there are other rows with the same UUID, and the flag

```
SELECT
    UUID 
FROM
    mytable m
WHERE
    flag = 'a'
AND
    (EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM 
            mytable
        WHERE 
           flag = 'b'
           and UUID = m.UUID

    ) OR
     EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM 
            mytable
        WHERE 
           flag = 'c'
           and UUID = m.UUID
        )
    )
```

or you can simpler write

```
SELECT
    UUID 
FROM
    mytable m
WHERE
    flag = 'a'
AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM 
            mytable
        WHERE 
           flag IN ('b','c')
           and UUID = m.UUID

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach using `min() and max()` functions:

```
select UUID
from Tbl
group by UUID having min(flag)="a" and min(flag)<>max(flag)
```

When `min()` is used with strings, the strings are ordered alphabetically A-Z and the first one is returned. In your case flags with `a` value will be the minimum and flags with `c` value will be the maximum. The having clause will ensure that there's an `a` value within the group and that value is not equal to the maximum flag value of the group (in this case `b or c`).

See a demo from [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uajybXWh7kFeHJdbuCc85f/0).

Comment: Unfortunately the example I gave is a simplified version of the "real" problem which has arbitrary strings for the flags. Moreover, your solution doesn't generalize to arbitrary conditions.